# CSS multiline link with adjustable underline thickness and vertical space between letters and underline

Tags: html, css

### Targets

1. Multiline link
2. Underline thickness is adjustable
3. Vertical space between letters and underline is adjustable (red lines in the picture below)
4. No wrappers allowed (1 link = 1 tag)

[image]

### Link creation approaches which I know

1. `text-decoration`: Vertical space between letters and underline is not adjustable
2. `display: inline-block` + `border-bottom` + `padding + bottom`: no multiline support

### Box shadow approach

With below solution, we have multi-line link with vertical space between letters and fat underline.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Link {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset -3px -6px 0 -4px blue;
 }
```

```html
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti <a href="#" class="Link"> quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.</a> Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
```

What wrong with this solution is it works only for `-3px -6px 0 -4px` box-shadow settings.
A little changes of box-shadow parameter will brake the view.

It means neither underline thickness nor vertical space between letters and underline are adjastable.

At least, it's unobvious how to adjust it.
I failed to understand how to adjust it experimentally.

Well, the CSS implementation could be arbitrary complicated, but it's complexity must be encapsulated to CSS preprocessor mixin. By other words, I need the API like:

```
@mixin multilineLink(
  underilineThickness,
  verticalSpaceBetweenLettersAndUnderiline
) {
  // ...solution
}
```

I can't believe if it's impossible: the multiline links with custom underline thickness and gap is basic demand of market, not aerobatics like complicated visual effects.

Comment: For customization borders use ::after or ::before.

Comment: @sm10, thank you for the advice. Would you please to add some fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a background gradient.

Thickness/Position of the line is adjustable by changing the % values as required.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Link {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 92%, blue 92%);
}
```

```html
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti <a href="#" class="Link"> quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.</a>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur
aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can we use absolute units like pixels in this solution?

Comment: You *could*, but you'd have to use `calc` to work out the pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

please try it.

```css
.link{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  text-decoration:none
}
p{
    line-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet <a href="#" class="link">dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel</a> eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry, but I must to tell about you solution limitation. That is the most upper line position depends on line height. Because paddings can not be negative, basically, the 1-2px gap is impossible...

Comment: sorry I can't undrestand the problem could you show me an example ? link or in your question ?

Comment: I'll explain or your example. Could you make the space between letters and underline to 2px? If we set `padding-bottom` to 0, the spacing space will be about 6px. I suppose, it's the limit.